# relative div that will take rest of div container

Tags: css

**Description:**
I have div container with absolute position that has flexible widtih&height changable by javascript. Then I have two children DIVS, that can change height, depends of elements inside them.
I need those divs to remain inside of parrent div.

**My problem:**
Second DIV is leaving parrent DIV's height, but I don't want that. I need it to be in remaining space, with scrollbarll.

(I have an image of project, but can't post yet.)

I have:

```
<div id="parrent"> <!-- This div is flexible and can change height !-->
  <div id="children_top"></div> <!-- This div is flexible and can change height !-->
  <div id="children_bot"></div> <!-- I need this div to take rest of the height space,     needs to have scrolling if it's longer than rest space !-->
</div>

<style>
#parrent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#children_top {
  background-color: #7f8f9f;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#childner_bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing your html structure slightly:

```
<div id="parrent">
    <div class="table">
        <div id="children_top" class="row">
        </div>
        <div id="children_bot" class="row">
            <div class="relative">
                <div class="scroll">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

You can use the following styles:

```
body, html {height:100%; min-height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;}
#parrent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
    bottom:0; right:0;
}
#children_top {
  background-color: #7f8f9f;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height:0px;
}
#children_bot {
  width: 100%; height:100%;
}

.table {display:table; height:100%; width:100%; }
.row {display: table-row; width:100%;}
.relative {position:relative; height:100%;}
.scroll {overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xCfD3/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you whanted??

```
<style>
        #parrent {
          position: absolute;
          background: yellow;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          height: 100%;
        }

        #container { 
          position: relative;
          background: blue;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }

        #children_top {
          background: red;
          width: 100%;  
          display: block;
          overflow: hidden;
          height: 50px;
        }

        #children_bot {
          background: green;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50px;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        }
</style>



<div id="parrent">
    <div id="container">
         <div id="children_top"></div> 
         <div id="children_bot"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

AND AT THE END ADD THIS!!!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#children_bot").css("top", $("#children_top").height() + "px");
    });
</script>
```

If I misunderstood you, you can send the image on unixe@hotmail.com

Comment: thanx for answer, but chilrden_top has flexible height, depends of elements inside

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Site already has a lot of javacsript. I would like to limit to html+css. But if other things will fail, I will do your way ofc.

Comment: Ok, if you really whant to use pure html and css use tables, a bit of styling and everything is done!

Answer (score 0):

Without making major changes to your existing markup and css:

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xqbb8/**

And this: **http://jsfiddle.net/xqbb8/1/**

You have to specify explicit height and width on the divs, like this:

```
#parrent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px; left: 64px;
  height: 60%; width: 60%;
  background-color:red;
}
#children_top {
  background-color: #7f8f9f;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#children_bot {
  height: 90%;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't specify % height of #children_top, it have to have height of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container `html` height first then you have  [**another solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwDB/1/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
}
#parrent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#children_top {
    background-color: #7f8f9f;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#childner_bottom {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parrent">
    <br/>
    <div id="children_top">This is some text in top</div>
    <div id="childner_bottom">This is some text in bottom</div>
    <br />
</div>
```